# Problem getting Form to be valid after validation Function is called

Tags: angular

I am having a problem with a password validation field. In my form i have 3 fields, one is the old password and the other is new password as well as confirm the new password. All works fine so far if the user enters the new password and confirms the password the form will become valid and he can submit. Now if the fields dont match and he edits the confirm password it will be valid. But if he makes the edit on the new password it will not.

Below is the function which checks the 2 fields and i see it get firered when i change either password field but it only makes the form valid when the change was made last on the confirm.

```
  static passwordMatchValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    const password: string = control.get('newPassword').value; // get password from our password form control
    const confirmPassword: string = control.get('confirmPassword').value; // get password from our confirmPassword form control
    // compare is the password math
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      // if they don't match, set an error in our confirmPassword form control
      console.log('No mathch' + password + ' - ' + confirmPassword)
      control.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({ NoPassswordMatch: true });
   }
  //  else {
  //    control.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({ NoPassswordMatch: false});
  //   }
  }
```

Here is also a stackblitz sample which demonstrates this issue. Please ignore the layout as i didn't want to spen to much time on making it look same as in my app

[StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/password-validation)

Comment: Add an else statement after your validation, and set all errors to null:     `control.get('confirmPassword').setErrors(null);
     control.get('newPassword').setErrors(null);`

Comment: the else control.get('confirmPassword').setErrors(null); did the trick, i dont want to clear the newPassword errors as there might be some other ones which would mean i overwrite the other validations.

Comment: No problem - will add my answer and you can mark as accepted...wasn't sure if you wanted to set all fields to valid or not so I suggested both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the errors as follows:

`control.get('confirmPassword').setErrors(null);`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return an object(explaining the error) if passwords do not match

```
static passwordMatchValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
  const password: string = control.get('newPassword').value; // get password from our password form control
  const confirmPassword: string = control.get('confirmPassword').value; // get password from our confirmPassword form control
  // compare is the password math
  if (password !== confirmPassword) {
    return {matchError: 'Passwords do not match'}
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/password-validation-zfzxpg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpassword%2Fcustom-validators.ts

Comment: Thanks the works to a degree but breaks the error message for me. the simple fix is the control.get('confirmPassword').setErrors(null); in the else statent which clears the error and makes form valid